# How to move all files to a directory in a same folder

Tags: directory

In a folder called 'my-folder', I have around 6000 mp4 files and one directory called 'videos'. I want to move these 6000 mp4 files to a directory called 'videos'. How can I do this? I am in 'my-folder' now. I came to this folder by cd commands in Putty.

Answer (score 1):

```
mv !(videos) videos
```

did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Read `man find`, `man xargs` and `man mv`. Then do something like:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty --max-args=512 mv --target-directory=videos/
```

But before you run this, check out what it produces by replacing `mv` with `echo mv`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname '*.mp4' -print0 | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty --max-args=512 echo mv --target-directory=videos/
```